# Cut string by substrings after none left

Tags: php, string, recursion, autoload, strrchr

I have a string `Field-Text-Datepicker`. I need to "explode" it to following array:

```
array(
    [0] => field-text-datepicker
    [1] => field-text
    [2] => field
);
```

I've tried some combinations of [`strrchr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php), [recursion](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-recursive-function-example-factorial-numbers) and [for loops](http://www.processing.org/reference/for.html), but everything I've made seem to be crazily complicated and ineffective. Is there some simple way I don't see? If not, I will post the mess I've already written. :)

### Why do I need it?

For better code organisation, I sometimes need to declare multiple classes per one file. This is a problem for my SPL autoloader, that loads files according to class names. Because of that, I need to get every possible filename to load from most probable to the least.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) with variable offsets:

```
$arr = explode('-', strtolower($str));    
for ($i = 1, $c = count($arr); $i < $c; $i++) {
    $result[] = implode('-', array_slice($arr, 0, -$i));
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/155283)

Answer (score 0):

There you go!
I just tested and it prints exactly what you need =)

```
<?php 
$str = "Field-Text-Datepicker";
$str = strtolower($str);
$array = explode('-',$str);
$count = count($array);
$output_array = [];
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
    $output_array[$count-$i] = implode('-',array_slice($array,0,$i));

var_dump($output_array); 
?>
```